# How to query the metadata(such as ttl) of record from aql?

Tags: aerospike, aql, aerospike-ce

Assume you have a set as follows:

```
+-------+-------+
| PK    | value |
+-------+-------+
| "pk1" | 24    |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.105 secs)
```

How to get the metadata for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the metadata, all you need to do is run this command before running the query:

```
set RECORD_PRINT_METADATA true
```

Now, when you query the set

```
select * from test.segments
```

you can see additional metadata of the set, as follows:

```
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+------------+-------+-------+
| PK    | value | {edigest}                      | {set}      | {ttl} | {gen} |
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+------------+-------+-------+
| "pk1" | 24    | "Rn/5rHEQGWvPOSBK+vHRMyLkFyo=" | "segments" | 57    | 1     |
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+------------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.175 secs)
```

NOTE:

1. The command has to be run just once. It holds true for all the queries that come after it.
2. To go back to the default behaviour, set the argument to `false`